# How to add multiple selected radio buttons to text field

Tags: java

I have a problem with radio button and text field. The action only uses the last radio button selected.

I have set up 3 different `ButtonGroup`, so you can select one radio button in each group.

In theory it should display 3 parameters (one from each group).  But it only display the parameter from the last radio button selected.

Here is the code where I add the actionlistener to each radio button and where I add the radio buttons to the `ButtonGroup`.  Also I included the `ActionListener` class.

I used JAVA GUI builder to build the GUI so nothing fancy.  The important part is the actionlistener and the display of radio buttons.  `bg`, `bg1`,and `bg2` are the `ButtonGroup`

```
[...]

    bg2.add(mixBtn);
    bg2.add(snowBtn);
    bg2.add(rainBtn);
    bg2.add(clearBtn);
    bg1.add(wetBtn);
    bg1.add(dryBtn);
    bg.add(hotBtn);
    bg.add(coldBtn);
    bg.add(mildBtn);

    handler h = new handler();
    mixBtn.addActionListener(h);
    snowBtn.addActionListener(h);
    rainBtn.addActionListener(h);
    clearBtn.addActionListener(h);
    wetBtn.addActionListener(h);
    dryBtn.addActionListener(h);
    hotBtn.addActionListener(h);
    coldBtn.addActionListener(h);
    mildBtn.addActionListener(h);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(45, 216, 722, 250);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}

class handler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField.setText("your weather is: " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] we don't know what layout you're using and how you're using it... `.setBounds(45, 216, 722, 250);` suggests that you're using  a `null-layout` and it could be the start of your problems...

Comment: Hey Frak, I don't think the layout is the problem here.  I think it has something to do with the actionlistener, seems like it only display the last radio button i clicked not all the clicked radio button.

Comment: Not related to the layout nor to the GUI. Look how many parameters you want to display and how many you use in your `setText()` call. (Hint: you have to check/fetch the other buttons value)

Comment: You're calling `setText(...)` and overwriting everything already held by the JTextField. If you want to append Strings, first **get** the text that the JTextField holds, then append the String and *then* **set** the JTextField with the new String.

Comment: And yeah, you *don't* want to use null layouts and `setBounds` as that leads to poor GUI programs.

Comment: Hovercraft, can you please give me an example on your first comment?  thanks

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels or whoever you're replying to, so they get notified (The `@` is important). What part don't you get? Iterate over each `ButtonGroup` and get the selected radio from each, concatenate each of these values into a variable and then just call `setText(theVariable);`

Comment: @ Frakcool how would you do that exactly?  bg is one of the ButtonGroup.  please give me an example.  something like this: String input=e.getActionCoomand(bg).  this obviously doesn't work.  this might be a simple fix, but i cant get my head over it right now.  thanks

Comment: First try to do it yourself. You learn by stretching your brain cells, not by asking others to write your code for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  my brain cell is stretched, that's why unasked for help.  I only ask for an example, not asking to write the whole code.  But I do appreciate the responds.